# filter out element in list that contains any characters in a list

Tags: r, dplyr

```
characters_to_filter <- ",.#"

myVector <- c("Mac.", "ved", "der,", "ght#", "hoy")
```

results:

```
myNewVector <- c("ved", "hoy")
```

I tried str_detect but it only works for one character. Is there a solution using dplyr?

Answer (score 2):

With `grep`, we construct the pattern with either `paste` or `sprintf` by wrapping the 'characters_to_filter' inside square bracket (`[]` - so that it will match either one of the characters or may have to `paste` with `|`, but that also needs to escape (`\\`) some of them as `.` can match any character as it is a metacharacter), specify the `invert = TRUE` to return the subset of vector which doesn't match the pattern

```
grep(sprintf('[%s]', characters_to_filter), myVector, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
[1] "ved" "hoy"
```

---

Or using `str_subset`

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(myVector, sprintf('[%s]', characters_to_filter), negate = TRUE)
[1] "ved" "hoy"
```

Or if we want to use `str_detect`, which returns a logical vector, which should then be used as index for subsetting

```
> str_detect(myVector, sprintf('[%s]', characters_to_filter), negate = TRUE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> myVector[str_detect(myVector, sprintf('[%s]', characters_to_filter), negate = TRUE)]
[1] "ved" "hoy"
```

Or with `str_c` and `str_detect`

```
> myVector[str_detect(myVector, str_c('[', characters_to_filter, ']'), negate = TRUE)]
[1] "ved" "hoy"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. I suppose str_detect in combination with str_c doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks akrun! I'll give your solutions a try and see which on is fastest.

Answer (score 2):

This one will remove all words with any special character:

- .*            match 1 or multiple character
- [[:punct:]]   match special character

then use str_subset(..., ".+") to remove empty string!

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(str_remove_all(myVector, ".*[[:punct:]]"), ".+")
```

```
[1] "ved" "hoy"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `str_detect` you can `filter` using the negation operator `!` in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(myVector) %>%
     filter(!str_detect(myVector, "[.,#]"))
  myVector
1      ved
2      hoy
```

`[.,#]` is a character class containing the characters to filter.